# Sporadic/random "class not found" errors in PHP Windows/IIS setup

Tags: php

We've been getting some seemingly random class not found errors in our PHP app. They happen out of the blue, seems completely random and doesn't happen often, weeks/months can go on without it happening. When it does happen, only solution seems to be restarting the web service, at which point everything goes back to normal. Autoloading is done through composer autoload > psr-4 configuration. Setup is IIS 7, PHP on FastCGI. It's not always the same class that is not found, it's a random class, different one every time, and usually it's a single class that's not found. All other classes being loaded using the same autoloading mechanism are found just fine.

Comment: `composer dump-autoload` doesn't offer solace?

Comment: Is it possible that there's a memory or load issue where sometimes it doesn't read the class files? I feel like you'd be seeing other issues before missing classes, though. Is it always the same class that's missing?

Comment: @JoshToth No, the class is different every time. I'll add that detail to the question. Also worth noting that it's a single class that's not found, other classes using the same autoloading mechanism are found just fine.

Comment: @lovelace I'll try that if it happens again to see if it solves the problem without having to restart the service. Still not great because it means the problem still happens and it has to be fixed, but at least it would be a small win.

Comment: @Rocket04 I'm pretty sure once PHP can't find a class, it will just show the error and quit. So it may fail on classes after the one it's showing, but it has already halted. Is IIS case-sensitive? I once had a class issue going from MacOS dev to Ubuntu production with differently-cased directories and files.

Comment: @JoshToth If you mean case-sensitive at the code level (vs at the file system level), yes it is. As far as other classes also failing, the reason I say they don't is that there are a number of other pages in the web app that load fine because they don't reference the offending class, so seems like all/most other classes are loading fine, based on entries I see in the error logs it appears all the errors are always referencing the same file once the error starts happening.